# Select top 10 from subquery of median CPU usage and display time series data with Influx

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I'm wanting to create a graph panel in Grafana which shows the top 10 highest consumers of CPU and show their respective history over whatever time interval has been selected. I think that last part is the tricky bit.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT TOP("median_Percent_Processor_Time", 10) as "usage", host FROM (
    SELECT median("Percent_Processor_Time") AS "median_Percent_Processor_Time" FROM "telegraf_monitoring"."autogen"."win_cpu" WHERE time > now() - 5s GROUP BY time(:interval:), "host" FILL(none)
)
```

This produces the following table:

```
time                | usage              | host
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 88.4503173828125   | CNVDWSO202
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 60.55384826660156  | CNVDSerr01
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 46.807456970214844 | NVsABAr01
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 27.402353286743164 | NVDARCH02
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 21.320478439331055 | NVDABAr05
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 5.546620845794678  | NVDALMBOE
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 3.654918909072876  | NVDLeNCXE01
12/17/18 02:38:36PM | 47.08285903930664  | NVDOKTARAD01
```

The table is useful but thats just a single point in time. I need to subsequently query and pull time series data from that win_cpu measurement for those 10 hosts. The hosts values are dynamic, I have no way of predicting what will show up and because of that I cant string together `OR` statements and Influx doesnt support `IN` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR regexp instead of `IN`. `=~ /HOST1|HOST2|HOST3/` + `GROUP BY host` and one InfluxDB query will return all data. The tricky part is Grafana variable, which will have those top 10 hosts. When you have it, then just use advance variable formatting in the regexp query - for example `=~ /${tophosts:pipe}/`.